# self as param, and setting scope?

Tags: lua

Can someone please help me with this.

```
local function TestPrice()
  local obj1 = require("myObj")
  local obj2 = require("myObj")

  obj1:setPrice(30)
  obj2:setPrice(40)
  print(obj1.price)    -- this prints '40'. Setting price on obj2 changes the price in obj1
end
```

and

```
-- myObj.lua
local M = {
price = -1;}

local function _setPrice(self, newprice)
  self.price = newprice
  -- todo other stuff
end

M.setPrice = _setPrice

return M
```

I thought that by setting *self* as a param it set the scope. Why does calling this function on obj2 update the value of obj1?

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on the rules of module loading but I'm like 70% certain that you can only 'require' files once, so obj1 and obj2 are just references to the same thing. Source: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require `The function starts by looking into the package.loaded table to determine whether modname is already loaded. If it is, then require returns the value stored at package.loaded[modname]`

Answer (score 2):

You need a function to create new object

```
-- myObj.lua
local M = {}

local function _setPrice(self, newprice)
  self.price = newprice
  -- todo other stuff
end

M.setPrice = _setPrice
M.__index = M

local function create_new_obj()
   local obj = {price = -1}
   setmetatable(obj, M)
   return obj
end

return create_new_obj


-- main.lua
local function TestPrice()
  local obj1 = require("myObj")()
  local obj2 = require("myObj")()

  obj1:setPrice(30)
  obj2:setPrice(40)
  print(obj1.price, obj2.price)
end

TestPrice()
```

Comment: I copied this line for line and it gives an exception; "attempt to call method 'setPrice' (a nil value)"

Answer (score 1):

In your code `require` load once, and second `require` give you [same object](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.3). You should implement some kind of copy method.

```
-- myObj.lua
local M = {
price = -1;}

local function _setPrice(self, newprice)
  self.price = newprice
  -- todo other stuff
end

function M:copy()
  return {["price"] = self.price, ["setPrice"]=_setPrice, ["copy"] = self.copy}
end

M.setPrice = _setPrice

return M
```

Comment: Any idea what the copy method would like like?